# Error mounting ESP prevents installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, system

I wanted to reinstall my system, because I got frequent error messages while booting. However, it did not work. I can "Try Ubuntu" but get error messages in the installation menu.

Apparently, the old OS was only partially removed. Whe I try to format the  partition, I get the following error message:

```
Der Versuch, ein Dateisystem vom Typ vfat auf SCSI1(0,0,0),Partition#1(sda) als /boot/efi einzubinden, ist fehlgeschlagen. Sie sollten die Partitionierung im Partitionierungsmenü fortsetzten.
```

Translation:

```
There was an error trying to mount a file system of the type vfat on SCSI1(0,0,0),Partition#1(sda) as /boot/efi. You should continue the partitioning in the partitioning menu
```

I can skip this error but during the installation I see the following warning in the terminal, which I assume is caused by the previous error.

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/fronted/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning Source ID 7804 was not found when attemping to remove it. GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
```

I also get errors when I try to install Windows.

Can anyone help me install my system?

Comment: Bitte verwende Englisch

Comment: That error message is about the EFI system partition. Which partition are you trying to format?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you should use Gparted to format the particular partition you wish to use to reinstall Ubuntu. Format as ext3 or ext4 not vfat. Ubuntu file systems are based on ext file systems. If it was Windows then NTFS would be used.

Try that and see if you are able to install Ubuntu

Comment: I don't think you understand - the EFI system partition has to be in a FAT format.